# Mongodb query not returning what I want

Tags: mongodb

**I am trying to return all the appUserID's with their latest created.**

Created is timestamp of the last record they made

```java
db.getCollection('<my collection>').aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        '$and': [
            {
                'companyID': < company ID > 
            },
            {
                'created': {
                    '$gte': < startDate timestamp > 
                }
            },
            {
                'created': {
                    $lt: < endDate timestamp > 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'appUserID': 1
    }
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$appUserID',
        'registrationsCount': {
            '$sum': 1
        },

    },

}, {
    '$sort': {
        'registrationsCount': - 1
    }
}])
```

This currently returns the appuserID and registrationCount and sorts it, but I can not manage to return appuserID and the latest timestamp

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you erases required fields with projection:

```
{
    '$project': {
        'appUserID': 1
    }
}
```

This instruction will erase all fields besides `appUserID`. To be able for the latest timestamp calculation you have to keep it in your aggregation pipeline:

```
{
    '$project': {
        'appUserID': 1,
        'created' : 1
    }
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$appUserID',
        'registrationsCount': {
            '$sum': 1
        },
        'latest': {
            $max: '$created'
        }
    },
}
```

I used `created` field but you can use any you want.

The result will be like:

```
{
    "_id" : <some id>,
    "registrationsCount" : <count>,
    "latest" : <some date>
}
```

Comment: @JamalWestfield don't forget to accept the answer ;)